# In an alg. which handles points (2D), but every point is actually a vector, how to label them as points?

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertices, simulated-annealing

I am trying to organize the vertices of a graph based on optimizing a cost function. At the moment I am using the Simulated Annealing algorithm.
The problem is that in the original algorithm we are looking for optimal points (in a 2D environment maybe) and in my case, every point is not just a point but some ordering of vertices.

E.g.: We have a graph with 3 vertices: I1, I2, I3. One point for me would be [I1 I2 I3] or [I2 I1 I3], so the final solution I have to get to is a certain ordering. Another point would be another combination of vertices.

So how would you refer, generically, to a point, given it represents a vector of numbers?
I am asking because the algorithm should be obviously modified..

Thank you!

Comment: could you "draw" what you have? Or the raw data and some more explanation? It's confusing for me.

Comment: i managed to do it, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a triangle you can use the center?